# Find value of key based on value in array within that key

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, ember.js

This is a brain teaser, so I'm using the places API (using an addon for ember.js so I don't really have control over the version unless I wanted to write my own) and it returns me data that looks like this

```
{
  "address_components": [
    {
      "long_name": "1235",
      "short_name": "1235",
      "types": [
        "street_number"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name": "Long Point Road",
      "short_name": "Long Point Rd",
      "types": [
        "route"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name": "Mount Pleasant",
      "short_name": "Mt Pleasant",
      "types": [
        "locality",
        "political"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name": "Charleston County",
      "short_name": "Charleston County",
      "types": [
        "administrative_area_level_2",
        "political"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name": "South Carolina",
      "short_name": "SC",
      "types": [
        "administrative_area_level_1",
        "political"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name": "United States",
      "short_name": "US",
      "types": [
        "country",
        "political"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name": "29464",
      "short_name": "29464",
      "types": [
        "postal_code"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name": "9020",
      "short_name": "9020",
      "types": [
        "postal_code_suffix"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "adr_address": "<span class=\"street-address\">1235 Long Point Rd</span>, <span class=\"locality\">Mt Pleasant</span>, <span class=\"region\">SC</span> <span class=\"postal-code\">29464-9020</span>, <span class=\"country-name\">USA</span>",
  "formatted_address": "1235 Long Point Rd, Mt Pleasant, SC 29464, USA",
  "geometry": {
    "location": {
      "lat": 32.8570647,
      "lng": -79.8224902
    }
  },
  "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png",
  "id": "f3d33a1a65adc47f7fcf927bb7b18ea91a59fb81",
  "name": "1235 Long Point Rd",
  "place_id": "ChIJkVjE8_5t_ogRvHeqOGZ6cB0",
  "reference": "CpQBjAAAAJEVbHvc6lTEXUvlKHc-wTI3f8g8U6W7i6oARvPyP_2TWTNE7IJQQHTABvbxTtMK6cFxRaksi2xaT7lcQiRB-nv7co7BVzfUMrwqr0YFQZvbLH_OGflPlO---vX4GPTQlDnFinnnixHW7LcRGbPJ4jfgnQ3HnURUCUmCa0WrLTIxiuqEwzIljAGv9K_iUMU9nBIQE57UebJ0CfCs9y0MBBvGeRoUUovGUbFYmgCnPOKVlXhrLQaE5uY",
  "scope": "GOOGLE",
  "types": [
    "street_address"
  ],
  "url": "https://maps.google.com/?q=1235+Long+Point+Rd,+Mt+Pleasant,+SC+29464,+USA&ftid=0x88fe6dfef3c45891:0x1d707a6638aa77bc",
  "vicinity": "Mount Pleasant",
  "html_attributions": []
}
```

So in the `address_components` part of the object you can see each object has a `types` key with values that pertain to what type they are, such as `street_number` or `route`. What I want to do is get the `short_name` (or `long_name`) of the object where `type` contains `street_number` or `route` and so on and so forth and be able to set those to variables or use them in some other way.

I've tried a few addresses and it returns them in roughly the same order, however sometimes there are one more or one less item in that array so it's not always returning the same amount of items in the exact same order. So rather than try to look at index and hope that's the right value I'm expecting I want to get these values based on what `type` says.

I am using ember.js so if there is a computed property way of possibly doing this that would be cool, but I'm open to using javascript/jQuery functions to do this.

Comment: how should a possible result look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a function

```
function getAdress(what, obj) {
    return obj.address_components.filter(function(item) {
        return item.types.indexOf(what) !== -1;
    }).shift();
}
```

and use it when you need to find something

```
getAdress('street_number', obj).short_name
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/60fhrrz3/1/)

Comment: nice answer @adeneo.  but what's the `shift()` doing?

Comment: @sfletche - as it's filtering an array, `shift` shifts off the first match in that array. From the OP's code, there would only be one match anyway.

Comment: According to the docs, "The shift() method removes the first element from an array and returns that element." Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift. Basically, @adeneo is using the fact that OP's JSON only has a single match on that field to return it (as he explained above). Well done.

Comment: thanks for the response @adeneo.  been using `unshift` for years and somehow neglected to look up `shift` before today...